# How to reserve a multi-dimensional Vector without increasing the vector size?

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, stdvector

I have data which is N by 4 which I push back data as follows.

```
vector<vector<int>> a;
for(some loop){
   ...
   a.push_back(vector<int>(4){val1,val2,val3,val4});
}
```

N would be less than 13000. In order to prevent unnecessary reallocation, I would like to reserve 13000 by 4 spaces in advance.

After reading multiple related posts on this topic (eg [How to reserve a multi-dimensional Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486840/)), I know the following will do the work. But I would like to do it with reserve() or any similar function if there are any, to be able to use `push_back()`.

```
vector<vector<int>> a(13000,vector<int>(4);
```

or

```
vector<vector<int>> a;
a.resize(13000,vector<int>(4));
```

How can I just reserve memory without increasing the vector size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data is guaranteed to be N x 4, you do *not* want to use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, but rather something like `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>`.

Why?

- It's the more semantically-accurate type - [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is designed for fixed-width contiguous sequences of data. (It also opens up the potential for more performance optimizations by the compiler, although that depends on exactly what it is that you're writing.)
- Your data will be laid out contiguously in memory, rather than every one of the different vectors allocating potentially disparate heap locations.

Having said that - @pasbi's answer is correct: You can use [`std::vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to allocate space for your outer vector before inserting any actual elements (both for vectors-of-vectors and for vectors-of-arrays). Also, later on, you can use the [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) method if you ended up inserting a lot less than you had planned.

Finally, one other option is to use a [`gsl::multispan`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45201524/1593077) and pre-allocate memory for it (GSL is the C++ Core Guidelines Support [Library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/guideline-support-library/info)).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You've already answered your own question.
There is a function [`vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) which does exactly what you want.

```
vector<vector<int>> a;
a.reserve(N);
for(some loop){
   ...
   a.push_back(vector<int>(4){val1,val2,val3,val4});
}
```

This will reserve memory to fit `N` times `vector<int>`. Note that the actual size of the inner `vector<int>` is irrelevant at this point since the data of a vector is allocated somewhere else, only a pointer and some bookkeeping is stored in the actual `std::vector`-class.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer is only here for completeness in case you ever come to have a similar problem with an unknown size; keeping a `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>` in your case will do perfectly fine.

To pick up on einpoklum's answer, and in case you didn't find this earlier, it is almost always a bad idea to have nested std::vectors, because of the memory layout he spoke of. Each inner vector will allocate its own chunk of data, which won't (necessarily) be contiguous with the others, which will produce cache misses.

Preferably, either:

- Like already said, use an std::array if you have a fixed and known amount of elements per vector;
- Or flatten your data structure by having a single `std::vector<T>` of size N x M.

```cpp
// Assuming N = 13000, M = 4

std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(13000 * 4);
```

Then you can access it like so:

```cpp
// Before:
int& element = vec[nIndex][mIndex];

// After:
int& element = vec[mIndex * 13000 + nIndex]; // Still assuming N = 13000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it will be allocated in contiguous space after flattened if I declare it as `vector<vector<int>> a;` and reserve space in advance. But it was a stupid idea thinking about the meaning of vector. :)